# Is there a term for when a component desolders itself from the circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, heat, terminology

When a chip heats up too much it could desolder itself from the circuit. Is there a technical term for that?

Comment: "Unscheduled disassembly"?

Comment: Disintegrated circuit? :)

Comment: There are some terms I've used when that's happened, but I don't think I can write them here.

Comment: Considering the temperature needed to reflow solder as well as the direction of the heat gradient, desoldering pins from pads is not something you need to be worried about -- internal connections within the chip have failed long before.

Comment: I've seen one motor controller that passed safety approval test because, with the motor short circuited, it failed safe with no fire danger. A resistor desoldered itself and fell off the PCB...

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Ok, passives might survive the experience.  But I don't think "chip" in the question meant a resistor.

Comment: @BenVoigt The connections have not failed or the desoldering would stop. The chip is quite possibly damaged, but I've seen MOSFETs still functional. The particular MOSFET had a very low thermal resistance junction-to-case so they may not have experienced damaging temperatures. Of course once the part falls off the board the heating ceases immediately (unless it falls into something even hotter- frying pan etc.).

Comment: Bad design? Inappropriate use?

Comment: Although the following technical term is perhaps a bit broad in scope, it does describe the situation that you describe.  The technical term that I would use is: "Oops!"

Comment: I've seen 1/4Watt resistors unsolder themselves before being visibly damaged.  One of my co-workers once used low value resistors to try to match the impedance of a coil to the output impedance of an amplifier.  It worked, sort of, but the resistors would get hot and unsolder themselves.  The people using the things were really unhappy - I got the task of redoing the impedance match in such a way as to not cause the things to self-destruct.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10022/12102

Answer (score 5):

Systems that have been known to experience this kind of failure mode (for example the early XBox-360 consoles) probably have some kind of deliberate thermal dissipation system (heat pipes, heat sinks etc) that have failed for some non-electronics related reason.

In the case of the XBox-360, some units failed because the GPU cooling was insufficient to prevent overheating, in conjunction with mechanical provisions not being strong enough to stop the SMD chips from sliding across the board once the solder melted.  Subsequent builds of the console featured upgrades to the mechanical fixings and to the active cooling components.

I think it is unlikely that there is a serious phrase that succinctly describes a generic desoldering event in mundane electronics.

Such things are system-level engineering failures.

Comment: I heard legends of people fixing their Xbox's by turning them on wrapping them in a blanket and placing them upside down in the hope that the xbox would resolder itself. I hope the stories are true!

Comment: I never owned a console myself, but I've witnessed the repair of such a sore case by baking the PCB in an oven at roughly 180°C for about 15min.

Comment: @Makoto, yes it is true.  Wrapping the whole console in a large damp towel (to restrict airflow) and running a graphics heavy game for a while was *said* to be a cure for the *intermittent* Red Ring of Death (RRoD) cases.  Total garbage of course.  It just turned the *intermittent* into the *absolute* :).

Comment: haha :) your comment got my hopes up

Comment: The stories are indeed true. I did the towel fix with my xbox and it worked, albiet for a few days only.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's called, or increasingly called these days, an "unscheduled thermal release event." Or, at least, that's what I've seen Toyota call it with regard to their Prius cars using NiMH battery systems.

(It also means that the designer didn't properly account for the ambient thermal environment and/or the motion of air or liquids related to removing accumulating heat energy from the immediate vicinity. But that's another story.)

Comment: One manufacturer's euphemistic phrase does not a technical term make :).

Comment: @Wossname No argument there. But at least it is "in the literature." Which is about as good as as answer can hope to get right now, I think. But point taken.

Comment: I wonder what Samsung (Galaxy 7) call it?

Comment: @Andyaka :) "unscheduled conflagration event followed by unscheduled thermal release events?"

Comment: @Andyaka, they probably call it something like "it's done a Bloggs?", where Bloggs is the name of the hapless engineer that is, alas, no longer with the company :)

Comment: Auto-Darwination, perhaps?

Comment: [Who coined the phrase 'Rapid Unscheduled Disassembly'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10022/12102)